# Having issues implementing Stripe in my Django Code

Tags: javascript, django, stripe-payments

I am implementing a stripe charge in my django ecommerce project. So In my views, I am trying to get the data from an input element in a form, then pass into a variable in the views.

Here is the Javascript that creates the input element

```
var form = document.getElementById('stripe-form');
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
    
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
    
    // Submit the form
    form.submit()
```

So in the `views.py`, I have this:

```
token = form.cleaned_data.get('stripeToken')
save = form.cleaned_data.get('save')
use_default = form.cleaned_data.get('use_default')
 print(form.cleaned_data)
```

the `print(form.cleaned_data)` returned a dictionary

`{'stripetoken':'', 'save': False, 'as_default': False}`

`stripetoken` maps to the `token` variable, and as you can see its value is empty. The last two variables that maps to the last two keys in the dictionary returned values.

**The `token = form.cleaned_data.get('stripeToken')` is supposed to get this `hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);` right?**

When I tried getting the value of `token.id`, I got a response. I used Javascript `alert(token.id)` to do that, and I got a value displayed in my browser. So I don't know what exactly is wrong.

Can someone help me out on this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `form.cleaned_data` print shows you've defined a form field called `stripetoken` (all lower-case), not `stripeToken` (camelCased).

Your JavaScript code is sending `stripeToken` (camelCased), but since there isn't a field by that name in your form, Django ignores the "extraneous" data sent by the browser and the cleaned data just includes the default for the field (which I will assume you've set to be `''`).

Fix your backend code to spell it `stripeToken`, or your frontend code to spell it `stripetoken`.

Comment: Oh, thanks I have seen the problem. I can't believe I spent so much time trying to figure out this